# .VOB files editing, converting and showing with right software

Tags: editing, encoding, vlc-media-player, vob, powerdvd

please Audio and video editing and encoding help me!
My problem is that:

last week with my camera (Panasonics VDR D160) i have filmed one of my company clinics.
Coming home, i move all the .VOB files writed on the mini DVD on my computer.
And now start the problems.
1) If i see this files with Vlc i can't go forward to a specific point to see that part of the clinics (that's not happens with power DVD 4)
2) I try to convert those VOB files in an avi files with Format Factory but when I ran this avi on Vlc or Power DVD or other player the video freeze but the audio proceed

My personal solution and request to all the superusers:

1) find a video editing software to split and join the vob files in some mini clip whit the interesting part of the clinics
2) find a player that have the option "go to" a specific time of the VOB files

Any other solution will be appreciated

This clips need me to a clinic that have to be done the next friday (30/08/2010) and the clip will be show with a Projector conncted to my laptop....yes I have very very few hours to solve my problem without a tecnical help

Thanks in advance to everyone that will help my prouposing a solutions am sorry for my worse english

Answer (score 0):

For point 2)
Try [KMPlayer](http://download.pandora.tv/?mode=kmp&tab=1) which plays VOB files and has a 'Go to' function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>).
e.g. to jump to 10min 30sec, 'Ctrl+Alt+g' and enter 10:30